# Composition of functions without last arguments

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors

Why doesn't `func4` work? I get an exception when I try to load it.

```
-- Works fine
func::Integer
func = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map (^2) $ [1..]

-- Works fine
func2::Integer
func2 = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd $ map (^2) [1..]

-- Works fine
func3::Integer
func3 = _func [1..] 
    where _func = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map (^2)

--Doesn't work!
func4::Integer
func4 = _func (^2) [1..] 
    where _func = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map
```

Exception message:

```
src.hs:3:63:
    Couldn't match type `[a] -> [b]' with `[c]'
    Expected type: (a -> b) -> [c]
      Actual type: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
    Relevant bindings include
      _func :: (a -> b) -> c (bound at src.hs:3:15)
    Probable cause: `map' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `map'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `filter odd . map'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: What is in that "exception"? Also that's now how you partially apply things.

Comment: I add the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_func (^2) [1..]
```

is the same as

```
(sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map) (^2) [1..]
```

And not

```
sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map (^2) $ [1..]
```

Becuse of kind of obvious (for me) reasons.

---

One of the possible solutions is making your `_func` take the mapped function:

```
func4::Integer
func4 = _func (^2) [1..] 
    where _func f = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map f
```

Comment: >One of the possible solutions is making your _func take the mapped function< 

Yes, I know. But I try to understand, why this don't work without the arguments for the `map` function. I learning the Haskell.

Comment: @Bush because the parameters are applied as "a list of two applications" to the whole, instead of feeding the first one to the map and second one to the whole function. Read my answer again.

Comment: But my both arguments are intended for the `map` function. Why you think the second one to the whole function? Is you mean whole function `sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map`?

Comment: @Bush because that is what you want. You want to compose partially applied `map` with the rest; if you want to **apply** (instead of composing) the rest on **fully applied** `map`, do `sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd $ map`.

Comment: Maybe I incorrect understand the *composition* and *applying*... I expect both my args will gotten by the `map`, its result will transferred as second parameter of the `filter`.

Comment: @Bush Read the comment above again.

Comment: `sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map $ (^2) [1..]` looks wrong to me, I'd expect `(sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd $ map (^2)) [1..]` wherein `filter` is fed a function instead of a list.

Comment: @chi Um, I don't think so? Look how `_func` is applied in the last example of OP.

Comment: Types do not match anyway, but `func_ (^2) [1..]` does not reduce to `something ((^2) [1..])` as your code implies: how is `(^2)` applied to `[1..]` ?

Comment: @chi damn it. I meant `(something) (^2) [1..]`, not `something ((^2) [1..])`

Comment: Probably you meant `(sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map $ (^2)) [1..]` with the extra parentheses?

Comment: @chi I think `where` simply builds a function and substitutes it directly, hence wrapping the where-introduced fn in the parens should yield the same result.

Comment: I expected the *composition* expected the same arguments as its last function (i.e. `map`). The `map` expects two arguments. But if the composition expects **only one argument always** (I remember the Haskell's functions can't to get more than one parameter) that the cause of error becomes obvious directly. Is the composition expects *only one argument always*?

Comment: @Bush yes, that's exactly the case. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the third example in pointfree notation, you can use the pointfree program

```
> pointfree "_func x = sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map x"
```

yields

```
_func = ((sum . takeWhile (< 10000) . filter odd) .) . map
```

Honestly, though, I think this is one of those examples that gives pointfree notation a bad name, I'd just keep the variables.

Comment: I don't understand this fragment of your code: `.) .`

Comment: @Bush- It is the same composition function you know and love, `(.)` ....  Granted, what you have pulled out is just a fragment, you have to look at the whole expression to make sense of it.  The whole expression is of the form `(<something>) . map` (this is where the `) .` comes from).  Inside the paren you have the other `(.)`, but as part of a partial application `(<somethingElse> .)`